# how can I change the background color of slider using jquery or css

Tags: jquery

Will u please tell me how can i change the background color of the slider using jquery and css when it slides.

I have used the method

.ui-slider-range{background:colorName};

Comment: Do you want it to be one color no matter where the slider is on the bar, or do you want the color to change based on where the slider is?

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps.

There is also a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ihusnjak/uhxPh/2/) of this example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide').slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            // from pure red to pure green
            var r, g, b = 0;
            g = Math.round(255 / 100 * ui.value); // 2.55 * (0 - 100) = 0 - 255
            r = 255 - g;
            var color = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
            $(this).css({
                'background': color
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can find algorithms for color lines out there somewhere ;-) This one I just made up.

p.s. I've added another "algorithm" into demo ;-)

Comment: Friend I don't want this code. The color should change when we slide the slider.

Comment: @user575300 Sorry, I'm a bit puzzled. Does it not change the background color of slider? You saw the demo, right? I'm guessing you need a different color change algorithm, or you need to change color of some other element? Or perhaps something third?

Comment: not sure why this answer wasn't accepted; anyway, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful. It's using JQuery to alter the css. all of my attempts, in my case, to set the CSS on the actual DIV, where the slider resided, failed? I guess the JQuery CSS libraries took precedence? It seems like over-kill. But this worked for me.

```
    var cs_style = "<style>#your_slider_div .ui-widget-header { background: #7D1515; } </style>";
    $('html > head').append(cs_style);
```

Running this ABOVE the jQuery function (definition and call) for your slider will set the background colour to a dark red colour. Of course, you can set it to what-ever you like. More than one way to crack the nut eh?

Comment: Of course, this just sets a different background colour to the standard default gray.